# From Kolkata to Guangzhou, China. Transit ticket to Bangkok suvarnabhumi airport

Tags: visas, transit, china

Hello I am Bangladesh Citizen currently studying in india and I am on a tourist  visa. In the month of October 2019 I am travelling to china for vacations and I booked a ticket from india to Bangkok and than form Bangkok to china with a layover time of 10 hours in Bangkok and I am not going to leave the airport but my flights are different, so do I need to get and Airport Transit Visa in Bangkok?

Comment: please don't ask the same question twice.  Edit the original first.